# Android strings xml file formatting

Tags: android, string, textview

Hy! I am working on my Android app and I want to format text so that my TextView shows this text on CONTACT US to look EXACTLY like on that website, but I dont know how to format it in strings.xml file. I have tried with basic HTML formatting putting `<br>` tag for new row and `<a>` tag for email adresses and web site, but nothing change. How to format it ? Can so large strings be saved into strings.xml ?

http://visitsplit.com/#pages?page=409

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` for new lines.

Further, you can use `Html.fromHtml` to create a `Spanned` that would have basic formatting - bold, italic, links, etc.

You would then need to override the movement method to actually make links operational:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML tags, like `<br>` and `<a>`, by using:

```
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_string)));
```

Make sure you properly escape any special characters in your strings.xml.